# jquery toggle to work in multiple instances

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle

I have a show/hide effect that works but I just need to be able to use it multiple times in a page. Currently it toggles all elements. Can't get my head around how to do it.

Hope you can help.

http://pastebin.me/29328e556caf53e9a1925030d65b864b

Comment: can you post some code on how you show and hide the elements?

Comment: just click on 'edit code' on right in pastebin.

Comment: just fyi i had already told you that you had to do an for each loop on your previous post about this same issue

Comment: thanks mmcgrail - I'm such a jquery noob I only understand when I see the code. Picking it up slowly;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your function a bit to this, it'll work on each `<ul>` indepdently:

```
$('.facet ul').each(function() {
  if($(this).children('li:gt(9)').hide().length === 0) return;
  $(this).append(
    $('<li id="toggler">More</li>').toggle(function() {
       $(this).text('Hide').siblings().show();
    }, function() { 
       $(this).text('More').siblings('li:gt(9)').hide();
    }));
});​
```

[See a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BkBST/)

Before, it was getting any `li` over 9, you want to do this **per** `<ul>` element with `.each()` like the example above.

Comment: Gotcha. Brilliant. Now I just need to integrate this with the expanding menu code below - should i create a new question?

http://pastebin.me/03b685f586fef84193b5fd72e815255d

Comment: @mark - For the sake of future googlers finding this, please do, and comment where it is here, I'll answer it if no one else does shortly.

Comment: will do. Although I can't post 2 url's yet.

Comment: @mark - Make sure to accept answers as well, this makes your questions more appealing to would-be answerers, gives you rep, them rep, the next person finding this a quick path to the right answer and closes out old questions, all good things.  Do this by clicking the checkmark beside the answer that helped you resolve the issue for each question.

Answer (score 0):

I removed a few bits to simplify, but you can see here for a working implementation...  To keep the togglers as li elements, you'll need to expand this to selectively hide sibling elements - but I'm a fan of simplicity, so I'd suggest keeping the togglers outside of the element you want to show/hide.

http://pastebin.me/7a7e139da8cad2b01593d895b668c17e

Comment: This doesn't do at all what the original script did...he wants to hide/show "more", not "all".

Comment: yea, it's more once it goes over a certain number the 'more' is displayed. and not if it is less. And then for this to work inside an expanding menu. BASically a space saver for typical indexhibt cms sites like : http://mikeyburton.com/